# Beginner: Pyqt 4 connecting touch keyboard to a Browser widget

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, pyqt

Can someone help me to connect the dots. Still learning how to program, and I'm trying to learn OOP by making a simple GUI in PYQT.

I am trying but don't know how to connect two widgets. One is a web browser example, and second one is a touch keyboard example. Touch keyboard needs to be invoked when touching line in browser widget to add url.

Code for MyBrowser widget :

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
from PyQt4.QtGui import QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QWidget

class UrlInput(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, browser):
        super(UrlInput, self).__init__()
        self.browser = browser
      # add event listener on "enter" pressed
        self.returnPressed.connect(self._return_pressed)

    def _return_pressed(self):
        url = QUrl(self.text())
      # load url into browser frame
        browser.load(url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # create grid layout
    grid = QGridLayout()
    browser = QWebView()
    browser.load(QUrl('http://google.com'))
    url_input = UrlInput(browser)
  # url_input at row 1 column 0 of our grid
    grid.addWidget(url_input, 1, 0)
  # browser frame at row 2 column 0 of our grid
    grid.addWidget(browser, 2, 0)

    # main app window
    main_frame = QWidget()
    main_frame.setLayout(grid)
    main_frame.show()

  # close app when user closes window
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Code for KeyboardTouch :

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from decimal import Decimal



# applicationle widgets
SIP_WIDGETS = [QtGui.QLineEdit]


class MyFlatPushButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, caption, min_size=(50, 20)):
        self.MIN_SIZE = min_size
        QtGui.QPushButton.__init__(self, caption)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(self.MIN_SIZE[0], self.MIN_SIZE[1])


class SoftInputWidget(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent_object, keyboard_type='default'):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.INPUT_WIDGET = None
        self.PARENT_OBJECT = parent_object
        self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)

        self.NO_ORD_KEY_LIST = list()
        self.NO_ORD_KEY_LIST.append(QtCore.Qt.Key_Left)
        self.NO_ORD_KEY_LIST.append(QtCore.Qt.Key_Up)
        self.NO_ORD_KEY_LIST.append(QtCore.Qt.Key_Right)
        self.NO_ORD_KEY_LIST.append(QtCore.Qt.Key_Down)
        self.NO_ORD_KEY_LIST.append(QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace)
        self.NO_ORD_KEY_LIST.append(QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter)
        self.NO_ORD_KEY_LIST.append(QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab)
        self.NO_ORD_KEY_LIST.append(QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape)

        self.do_layout(keyboard_type)

        self.signalMapper.mapped[int].connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def do_layout(self, keyboard_type='default'):
        """
        @param   keyboard_type:
        @return:
        """
        gl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setFont(self.PARENT_OBJECT.font())
        number_widget_list = []
        sym_list = range(0, 10)
        for sym in sym_list:
            button = MyFlatPushButton(str(sym))
            button.KEY_CHAR = ord(str(sym))
            number_widget_list.append(button)

        button = MyFlatPushButton('*')
        button.KEY_CHAR = ord('*')
        number_widget_list.append(button)

        # alphabets
        alpha_widget_list = []
        sym_list = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'z', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p','@',
                    'new_row',
                    'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', '-', '/',
                    'new_row',
                    'y', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', ':']

        for sym in sym_list:
            if sym == 'new_row':
                alpha_widget_list.append('new_row')
            else:
                button = MyFlatPushButton(sym)
                button.KEY_CHAR = ord(sym)
                alpha_widget_list.append(button)



        # back space
        control_widget_list = []

        # close
        button = MyFlatPushButton('Esc')
        button.KEY_CHAR = QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape
        control_widget_list.append(button)
        control_widget_list.append('sep')

        button = MyFlatPushButton('Del')
        button.setToolTip('Backspace')
        button.KEY_CHAR = QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace
        control_widget_list.append(button)
        control_widget_list.append('sep')

        # tab
        button = MyFlatPushButton('TAB')
        button.KEY_CHAR = QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab
        control_widget_list.append(button)
        control_widget_list.append('sep')

        # space
        button = MyFlatPushButton('Space', min_size=(70, 30))
        button.KEY_CHAR = QtCore.Qt.Key_Space
        control_widget_list.append(button)
        control_widget_list.append('sep')



        # enter
        button = MyFlatPushButton('ENTER', min_size=(60, 30))
        button.KEY_CHAR = QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter
        control_widget_list.append(button)
        control_widget_list.append('sep')

        alist = list()
        alist.append((QtCore.Qt.Key_Left, 'Left'))
        alist.append((QtCore.Qt.Key_Right, 'Right'))
        alist.append((QtCore.Qt.Key_Up, 'Up'))
        alist.append((QtCore.Qt.Key_Down, 'Down'))

        for key in alist:
            button = MyFlatPushButton(key[1])
            button.KEY_CHAR = key[0]
            control_widget_list.append(button)

        MAX_COL = 10
        col = 0
        tlist = list()

        if keyboard_type == 'numeric':
            widget_list = number_widget_list
        elif keyboard_type == 'alpha':
            widget_list = alpha_widget_list
        else:
            widget_list = list()
            widget_list.extend(number_widget_list)
            widget_list.append('new_row')
            widget_list.extend(alpha_widget_list)

        widget_list.append('new_row')
        widget_list.extend(control_widget_list)

        for widget in widget_list:
            if widget == 'new_row':
                col = MAX_COL
            elif widget == 'sep':
                tlist.append(self.get_vline())
                continue
            else:
                tlist.append(widget)
                widget.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
                self.signalMapper.setMapping(widget, widget.KEY_CHAR)

            if col == MAX_COL:
                col = 0
                v = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
                v.addStretch()
                v.setSpacing(2)
                map(v.addWidget, tlist)
                v.addStretch()
                gl.addLayout(v)
                tlist = []
            else:
                col += 1

        v = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        v.setSpacing(5)
        v.addStretch()

        map(v.addWidget, tlist)
        v.addStretch()
        gl.addLayout(v)
        gl.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        gl.setSpacing(3)
        gl.setSizeConstraint(gl.SetFixedSize)

        self.setLayout(gl)


    #moguce za iskoristi za back botun
    def reject(self):
        self.buttonClicked(QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape)

    def buttonClicked(self, char_ord):
        w = self.INPUT_WIDGET
        if char_ord in self.NO_ORD_KEY_LIST:
            keyPress = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, char_ord, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier, '')
        else:
            keyPress = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, char_ord, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier, chr(char_ord))

        # send keypress event to widget
        QtGui.QApplication.sendEvent(w, keyPress)

        # line edit returnPressed event is triggering twice for press and release both
        # that is why do not send release event for special key
        if char_ord not in self.NO_ORD_KEY_LIST:
            keyRelease = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, char_ord, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier, '')
            QtGui.QApplication.sendEvent(w, keyRelease)

        # hide on enter or esc button click
        if char_ord in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape):
            self.hide()

    def show_input_panel(self, widget):
        self.INPUT_WIDGET = widget
        self.show()
        self.update_panel_position()

    def update_panel_position(self):
        widget = self.INPUT_WIDGET
        if not widget: return

        widget_rect = widget.rect()
        widget_bottom = widget.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(widget.frameGeometry().x(), widget.frameGeometry().y())).y()
        screen_height = QtGui.qApp.desktop().availableGeometry().height()
        input_panel_height = self.geometry().height() + 5

        if (screen_height - widget_bottom) > input_panel_height:
            # display input panel at bottom of widget
            panelPos = QtCore.QPoint(widget_rect.left(), widget_rect.bottom() + 2)
        else:
            # display input panel at top of widget
            panelPos = QtCore.QPoint(widget_rect.left(), widget_rect.top() - input_panel_height)

        panelPos = widget.mapToGlobal(panelPos)
        self.move(panelPos)

    def _get_line(self, vertical=True):
        line = QtGui.QFrame()
        line.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        if vertical is True:
            line.setFrameShape(line.VLine)
        else:
            line.setFrameShape(line.HLine)
        line.setFrameShadow(line.Sunken)
        return line

    def get_hline(self):
        return self._get_line(vertical=False)

    def get_vline(self):
        return self._get_line()


class TouchInterface(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, PARENT_WIDGET):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self._PARENT_WIDGET = PARENT_WIDGET
        self._input_panel_all = SoftInputWidget(PARENT_WIDGET, 'default')
       # self._input_panel_numeric = SoftInputWidget(PARENT_WIDGET, 'numeric')

    def childEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ChildAdded:
            if isinstance(event.child(), *SIP_WIDGETS):
                event.child().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if self._PARENT_WIDGET.focusWidget() == widget and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if hasattr(widget, 'keyboard_type'):
                if widget.keyboard_type == 'default':
                    self._input_panel_all.show_input_panel(widget)
               # elif widget.keyboard_type == 'numeric':
                  #  self._input_panel_numeric.show_input_panel(widget)

        return False


class TouchInputWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.touch_interface = TouchInterface(self)

    def childEvent(self, event):
        self.touch_interface.childEvent(event)

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        return self.touch_interface.eventFilter(widget, event)


class ExampleWidget(TouchInputWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        TouchInputWidget.__init__(self)

        #self.txtNumeric = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        # actiate touch input
       # self.txtNumeric.keyboard_type = 'numeric'

        self.txtText = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        # activate touch input
        self.txtText.keyboard_type = 'default'

        gl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
       # gl.addWidget(self.txtNumeric)
        gl.addWidget(self.txtText)

        self.setWindowTitle('Touch Input Demo')
        self.setLayout(gl)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    ExampleWidget().show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so sure I understood what you need,from where I see you just want to show up some keyboard when clicking inside a QLineEdit. If it is what you need I would tell you to use signal and override some default methods and implement the wanted behavior inside it.

Have a look at this small example, see if it makes sense and if you could use this reasoning into your app ")

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.cw_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.cw_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.line = LineEdit()
        self.kb = KeyBoard()

        self.cw_layout.addWidget(self.line)

        self.create_connections()

    def create_connections(self):
        self.line.signal_evoke_kb.connect(self.show_kb)

    def show_kb(self):
        if self.kb.isHidden():
            self.kb.show()
        else:
            self.kb.hide()


class LineEdit(QLineEdit):

    signal_evoke_kb = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__()

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        super(LineEdit, self).mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent)
        self.signal_evoke_kb.emit()

class KeyBoard(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(KeyBoard, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        for key in ['q','w','e','r','t','y']:
            self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton(key))
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**I'm using PyQt5 so probably you would just have to change the imports.**

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try to implement your example in my app! I needed to understand how to call a widget "touch keyboard" every time when I click on line for edit "QLineEdit".  And this example of web browser confused me because of  this class UrlInput (QLineEdit). That class calls a QLineEdit and because of my lack of experience I don't know how implement "Touch keyboard" there.

Comment: Yeah, I totally understand, just get in mind that every time you need a variation of something you gotta create a class, extend that class and override some methods from its inheritance. Another good thing you should have a look is Filter and filter installation, those are the best ways to get events you want to catch in Qt. Just have a look in the API, there are really really great examples, and no doubt StackOverflow too ")